# relativeCreated in log module

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

The `relativeCreated` is defined in the [`logging module`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html) as:

> Time in milliseconds when the LogRecord was created, **relative to the time the logging module was loaded**.

How is the part in bold defined? For example is it:

```
# when it is first imported?
import logging # what if another module/library imports it before this call?
```

Or is it:

```
# when the root logger was initialized?
logging.basicConfig(filename='x.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format=LOGGING_FORMAT_STRING)
```

Or is it:

```
# when the specific logger was initialized?
logger = logging.getLogger('my_app')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

```
import logging
```

The start time is set by a module level [statement](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L57). In general "loading" a module is the same as importing it.

If you want to you can even check what the timestamp is that it uses as the begin of time.

```
import logging
print(logging._startTime)
```